# Can OpenVPN client talk to Array Networks server?

Tags: vpn, openvpn, vpn-client

Our hosting provider (an IBM-owned one) provides [two VPN-options](https://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/topic/vpn):

- [Java embedded in browser](https://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/procedure/ssl-vpn-connections): Windows, MacOS, Linux
- GUI-client -- [MotionPro](http://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/articles/standalone-vpn-clients-windows-linux-and-mac-os-x): Windows, MacOS, Linux

Neither option works for a FreeBSD-user...

Simply pointing OpenVPN client at one of their [listed end-points](https://www.softlayer.com/VPN-Access) fails -- the client keeps resetting connection.

I doubt, they are using a truly proprietary protocol, but simply opening one of the end-points in the browser redirects to `https://ENDPOINT/prx/000/http/localhost/login`

Can OpenVPN be configured to work with such a server?

Comment: I was never able to figure this (and others) out so I just maintain a small windows VM that I power up for this sort of thing.

Comment: Ha! I woudn't debase myself even with Linux, much less Windows...

Comment: Sucks to be you.